# ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor jQuery Full Calendar JSON datetime format

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, fullcalendar

I am implementing FullCalendar jquery with asp.net mvc 3. It's working fine but the events are not being returned to the calendar. Firebug console is telling me that they are definitely being returned, they just aren't showing up on the calendar. I think this is something to do with the date format, I've read around but can't get anything to work. Here is my controller;

```
public ActionResult CalendarData()
{
    DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;

    var eventlist = from e in db.WhatsOns
                    where e.start >= myDate && e.CalenderDisplay
                    select e;

    return Json(eventlist.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

And the javascript in my view;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {            
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
       center: 'title',
        right:''

    },
    defaultView: 'month',
    editable: false,
     events: "/WhatsOn/CalendarData"
   });
}); 

</script>
```

The cosole output is as follows;

```
[{"ID":1,"start":"\/Date(1312844400000)\/","end":"\/Date(1313103600000)   \/","Name":"Test","Desc":"This is a test event, it will be       great!","link":"http:www.link./com","CalenderDisplay":true,"day":null,"whtscount":0,"isActive":false},{"ID":2,"start":"\/Date(1313708400000)\/","end":"\/Date(1314054000000)\/","Name":"This another test event5, it\u0027s on later than the first one.","Desc":"We aere all gpoing to get together and drink,","link":"http:www.link./com","CalenderDisplay":true,"day":null,"whtscount":0,"isActive":false}]
```

Comment: What format are they being returned in? Could you please add the Console output?

Comment: added. The format is  "/Date(1313103600000)/"

Comment: Just saw your edit, "title" is, i think, what is causing the problem for you.

Comment: Ah, I think this might be duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544010/jquery-full-calendar-not-showing-events

Comment: It will take me a few minutes to add title to my data model and test it. Back i9n a mo, I'll mark Nemanja as answer if it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: And I'll try the dupe answer in andyb's response if that doesn't work..

Comment: so I added the 'public string title {get; set;} to my data model to no avail. Still get the same result. I'll try the other answer now..

Comment: It worked! You're all gorgeous. Both of you helped equally, without 'title' it wouldn't have worked and without andyb pointing me toward that answer it wouldn't have worked. How do I share the spoils?!!

Comment: just glad I could be of help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a same problem recently, not native in .net, but might be the same issue -

Full calendar requires an array whose every element has clearly defined title and start indexes, at least.

In other words, i didn't get the events shown, until i formatted the json my action was returning to something like this ( this is json from my app that works ):

```
events: [
    0: {sessionId:259, title:Completed regular, start:2011-08-08}
    1: {sessionId:260, title:Completed regular, start:2011-08-10}
    2: {sessionId:261, title:Not done, start:2011-08-12}
    3: {sessionId:262, title:Not done, start:2011-08-13}
    4: {sessionId:263, title:Not done, start:2011-08-15}
    5: {sessionId:264, title:Not done, start:2011-08-17}
]
```

Hope this helps,

Cheers

Comment: Hi Nemanja, thanks for your reply. I have an ID and a start date. I'll add a title to my data model, but I'm not sure how to convert the date format json returns to a format fullcalendar can use. Could you explain how you formatted the json result? I know you said it isn't .net, but ay advice would be great!Thanks again!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544010/jquery-full-calendar-not-showing-events , someone already had a same problem concerning date parsing, accepted answer seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find that the [JSON specification](http://json.org/) does not support readily serializing datetime type objects, so given your nearest exchangeable representation, I'd suggest transmitting dates as strings (a workaround I had to use in a recent AJAX-enabled application). Using [.NET's Date.Parse() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) on strings generated by the [JavaScript Date.toUTCString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString), and calling [JavaScript's Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) with the string generated by the native [.NET Date.ToString() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a095fsay.aspx), I was able to exchange datetime data easily between my .NET application and JavaScript. I would suggest this approach.

Keep in mind your application may demand UTC representations of times in your datastore if you are supporting datetime localization where your server time zone differs from application users. I'd recommend using the [RFC1123 pattern specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#RFC1123) when calling .NET's ToString() for time localization. JavaScript's Date constructor can easily parse this format.

Comment: Thaks for the advice. I'm going to get the site working according to spec than go back and tidy it for future versions. The thread @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544010/jquery-full-calendar-not-showing-events fixed my issue.